# Installing public package using `npm i curlconverter` results in `fatal: Could not read from remote repository`

Tags: npm, dockerfile, npm-install

There already is an issue about this on github however the proposed solution does not solve the problem. I am also not knowledgeable enough to know if this is a bug in the library or not.

```
$ npm i curlconverter
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/NickCarneiro/yargs-ansi.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2021-05-17T14_07_32_675Z-debug.log
```

I am able to install `curlconverter` locally by installing an older version:

```
npm install --save yargs
npm install --save curlconverter@3.12.0
```

However if I do this in a Dockerfile it still errors:

```
Step 6/9 : RUN npm install --save curlconverter@3.12.0
 ---> Running in 2f5e6c7af7ce
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/NickCarneiro/yargs.git
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-05-17T14_06_02_821Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install --save curlconverter@3.12.0' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What is the problem here and is there any way to install and use the package?